# Embedded iFrame with Responsive Sizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm writing a component of my website that will eventually be embedded on other sites via an iframe. However, I'd like the height of the iframe on the embedded page to be able to dynamically adjust based on the height of the embedded content (which varies by screen size).

Additionally, I need the iframe's height to be responsive (i.e. it automatically adjusts when the screen size is changed).

I'm thinking that the embedded code will probably look like such:

```
<iframe src="/path/to/embedded/page" other-properties />
<script src="/path/to/script/from/my/site" />
```

However, can you point me in the right direction as to where to start to write a script that would dynamically adjust the height of the iframe depending on screen size?

Answer (score 1):

for the width of your iframe 
you can adjust the width of your iframe based on its container

example

```
<div class="container_of_iframe" style="width:200px;">
  <iframe src="/path/to/embedded/page" style="width:100%;" />
  <script src="/path/to/script/from/my/site" />
 </div>
```

for the height you can also specify the height of your iframe based on its container ,but it's better to make it with fixed height as some times you don't know the container height ,also the container maynot be a block element so the iframe height willnot be relative to the container

```
<div class="container_of_iframe" style="width:200px;">
  <iframe src="/path/to/embedded/page" style="height:300px;" />
  <script src="/path/to/script/from/my/site" />
</div>
```

for more info check these links

[example of responsive iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/masau/7wrhm/)

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/

Comment: I can't use a fixed iframe height - it will vary by screen size. Your code may cause the iframe to be too big on some screens and too small (and thus require a scroll bar, which I don't want) on others.